# How to match float numbers without empty matches

Tags: regex

I've custom regex where I match float numbers.

**Regex:**

```
/[0-9]*\,?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*/m
```

When I tried with string `1,5$+absd1.5a` get 10 matches on result where **1** match == **1,5** and **8** match = **1.5**. Other matches is empty. How I can match without empty results?

**Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/jnhsly/1

Comment: Try `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?`

Comment: Great! @WiktorStribiżew It's work for me.